# Custome Actions with different vbs script using Configuration Manager VS 2010 MSI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

Hi I'm wondering if there is a way to make a MSI add a different file based on the configuration manager in Visual Studio 2010. I know this is done when using Output from a project. But can this also be done with different files in development.

I have two different vbs scripts that I would like to run different in Custome Actions when using debug or release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio setup projects do not support dynamic sources for your application files.

A solution is to use a common deployment folder for both your application configurations. Your setup project can then use that folder. This way the package will use whatever was generated last in your deployment folder.

Other setup authoring tools support path variables. Basically, instead of using hard-coded paths you can use a dynamic variable.